# How to use addAll and retainAll methods in HashSet

Tags: java, generics, hashset

When I try to compile I get an error message for my makeUnion method and I'm guessing I will get one for makeIntersection too. I'm not sure why this is, or how to implement makeUnion if I want to add a set interface to the new set. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Set<T> implements SetInterface<T>
{
private HashSet<T> set;

/**
 * Constructs a new empty set.
 */
public Set () {
    set = new HashSet <>();
}

/**
 * Constructs a new set containing the elements in the specified collection. 
 * Default load factor of 0.75 and initial capacity of 50.
 * 
 * @param c- the collection whose elements are to be place into this set
 */
public Set(Collection <? extends T> c) {
    set = new HashSet<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 50));
    set.addAll(c);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new empty set. Default load factor of 0.75.
 * 
 * @param initialCapacity- the initial capacity of the hash table
 */
public Set(int initialCapacity) {
     set = new HashSet <>(initialCapacity);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new empty set. 
 * Hashmap has specified initial capacity and specified load factor.
 * 
 * @param initialCapacity- the initial capacity of the hash table
 *        loadFactor- the load factor of the hash map
 */
public Set(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
     set = new HashSet <>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}

/**
 * Add an item of type T to the interface  Duplicate items will not be
 * added to the set.
 * 
 * @param  itemToAdd - what to add.
 */
public void add(T itemToAdd) {
    set.add(itemToAdd);
}

/**
 * Removes an item from the set ( if the item is in the set)  If the item is not
 * in the set this operation does nothing
 * 
 * @param  item to remove. 
 */
public void remove( T itemToDelete) {
    set.remove(itemToDelete);
}

/**
 * Return if the SetInterface contains an item
 * 
 * @param itemToCheck.  The item you are looking for
 * @return  true if found.  False if not found.
 */
public boolean contains( T itemToCheck) {
    return set.contains(itemToCheck);
}

/**
 * Make a union of two sets.  We add all items in either set to a new set and
 * return the new set.
 * 
 * @param the 'other' set to add to our set.
 * @return  A new set which is the union of the two sets. 
 */
public Set<T> makeUnion( SetInterface<T> otherSet) {
    return set.addAll(otherSet);
}

/**
 * Make an intersection  of two sets.  We add create a new set which only has
 * items in it that are contained in both sets.
 * 
 * @param the 'other' set to intersect with 
 * @return  A new set which is the intersection  of the two sets. 
 */
public Set<T> makeIntersection( SetInterface<T> otherSet) {
    return set.retainAll(otherSet);
}

/** 
 * Return an iterator for the set.  This is used to walk thought all elements
 * in the set
 * 
 * @return  The iterator
 */
public Iterator<T> getIterator() {
    return set.iterator();
}

/**
 * Tell the caller how many elements are in the set
 * 
 * @return int with the number of elements
 */
public int size() {
    return set.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the javadoc and see what return value of [`HashSet.addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) is? You should, because it's not what you apparently think it is. Down-voting for lack of research.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The standard `HashSet` has no idea about your custom `SetInterface`. Therefore, you can’t pass instances of `SetInterface` directly to `HashSet`’s methods and expect it to magically do the right thing. But besides that it can’t handle your parameter argument, it also doesn’t return what you expect. That’s what you learn when following Andreas’ advice of reading the documentation, but reading the compiler’s error message would help too.

Answer (score -1):

```
      interface SetInterface<T> {
      void add(T itemToAdd);
      public void remove( T itemToDelete);
    public boolean contains( T itemToCheck);
    public Set<T> makeUnion( SetInterface<T> otherSet);
    public Iterator<T> getIterator();
    public int size();
    HashSet<T> getSet();
      }

      public class Set<T> implements SetInterface<T>
    {
    private HashSet<T> set;
    public HashSet<T> getSet() {
    return set;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new empty set.
     */
    public Set () {
        set = new HashSet <>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new set containing the elements in the specified collection. 
     * Default load factor of 0.75 and initial capacity of 50.
     * 
     * @param c- the collection whose elements are to be place into this set
     */
    public Set(Collection <? extends T> c) {
        set = new HashSet<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 50));
        set.addAll(c);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new empty set. Default load factor of 0.75.
     * 
     * @param initialCapacity- the initial capacity of the hash table
     */
    public Set(int initialCapacity) {
         set = new HashSet <>(initialCapacity);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new empty set. 
     * Hashmap has specified initial capacity and specified load factor.
     * 
     * @param initialCapacity- the initial capacity of the hash table
     *        loadFactor- the load factor of the hash map
     */
    public Set(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
         set = new HashSet <>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    /**
     * Add an item of type T to the interface  Duplicate items will not be
     * added to the set.
     * 
     * @param  itemToAdd - what to add.
     */
    public void add(T itemToAdd) {
        set.add(itemToAdd);
    }

    /**
     * Removes an item from the set ( if the item is in the set)  If the item is not
     * in the set this operation does nothing
     * 
     * @param  item to remove. 
     */
    public void remove( T itemToDelete) {
        set.remove(itemToDelete);
    }

    /**
     * Return if the SetInterface contains an item
     * 
     * @param itemToCheck.  The item you are looking for
     * @return  true if found.  False if not found.
     */
    public boolean contains( T itemToCheck) {
        return set.contains(itemToCheck);
    }

    /**
     * Make a union of two sets.  We add all items in either set to a new set and
     * return the new set.
     * 
     * @param the 'other' set to add to our set.
     * @return  A new set which is the union of the two sets. 
     */
    public Set<T> makeUnion( SetInterface<T> otherSet) {
    set.addAll(new java.util.ArrayList<T>(otherSet.getSet()));
        return this;
    }

    /** 
     * Return an iterator for the set.  This is used to walk thought all elements
     * in the set
     * 
     * @return  The iterator
     */
    public Iterator<T> getIterator() {
        return set.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * Tell the caller how many elements are in the set
     * 
     * @return int with the number of elements
     */
    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }
    }
```

Comment: why arrayList and not HashSet?

Comment: also that doesn't compile because getSet() is not in the given set interface. We are not allowed to edit the given interface.

Comment: A code dump by itself is not an acceptable answer.  Are you expecting readers to compare your code line-by-line with the code in the original question?  Explain what you changed, and why.